# How to make a triangular shaped plane

Tags: modeling

I am relatively new to blender and I want to make a triangle shaped plane in blender. Not a pyramid, just a plane shaped like a triangle. Thanks in advance

Comment: related:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16294/make-a-triangle-with-exact-dimensions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create ***equilateral triangle*** fast you may do it:

- #### USING A CONE

  Add a *cone* and set its vertices number to 3 via the Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>). Then delete the very top vertex with <kbd>X</kbd>.

  [image]
- #### USING MESH EXTRA OBJECTS ADD ON (REGULAR SOLID)

  Activate the ***Extra Objects*** add on via User Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). Then go to *Mesh*-->*Math Function*-->*Regular Solid*. Delete the top vertex finally.

  [image]
  [image]

Comment: There is a triangle object in  mesh extra objects now (daily builds for now) if you want to add that to your answer.  :)

Comment: @Timaroberts Cool! Didn't know about it. I'll update my answer as soon as I get the new release. THNX!

Answer (score 6):

Add a circle and set it to have 3 vertices.

Set the fill to Ngon or Triangle fan

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Create a plane and go into edit mode with tab. Select two of the vertices and use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to merge them at center. 
[image]
The end result is a triangle.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the **Spin** tool in Edit Mode and rotate a single edge around one of its vertices. Make the 3D cursor pivot for that, set Steps to **1**, give any Angle and you're done. Still, if you want an **equilateral** triangle set Angle to 60. By analogy, it's 90 degrees for the **right** triangle.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth Ciekawe rozwiązanie. Pozdrawiam :).